# How to apply weight option in networkx HITS algorithms

Tags: networkx

I would like to derive the hub, authority score of  [HITS algorithm](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.hits_alg.hits.html#networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.hits_alg.hits).

I have a directed, weighted graph 'H'

It is not difficult to calculate simple(unweighted) hub, authority scores from networkx module.

However, I don't know how to get the weighted('amt' in my data) hub, authority scores.

In the contrast that, [PageLink](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html#networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank) offers 'weight' option.

I attached example code as belows.

Thank you.

```
# unweighted HITS algorithm
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'sender' : ['1','2'], 'receiver' : ['3','3'], 'amt' : [100, 200]})
H = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = 'sender', target = 'receiver', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
h, a = nx.hits(H)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to source code,

I should make and infile a column that named 'weight'.

When I need to use from_pandas_edgelist, I have to create 'attr_edge = 'weight''.